# How to subtract values from associated factor level across the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple question. I have a dataframe `df`

```
>df <- data.frame(Diet = c("A","A","B","C","A","C"),
                 Variable = c("hpv", "smc", "smc", "smc","lpc", "lpc"),
                 Value1 = c(5, 3, 7, 10, 1, 9),
                 Value2 = c(0.3, 0.56, 1.34, 1.5, 0.7, 2.4))

>df
  Diet Variable Value1 Value2
1    A      hpv      5   0.30
2    A      smc      3   0.56
3    B      smc      7   1.34
4    C      smc     10   1.50
5    A      lpc      1   0.70
6    C      lpc      9   2.40
```

I would like to first group by `Variable`, then set `Diet == A` as a reference from which `value1` and `value2` of the same `Variable` are subtracted. The expected output is

```
  Diet Variable Value1 Value2
1    A      hpv      0      0
2    A      smc      0      0
3    B      smc      4   0.78
4    C      smc      7   0.94
5    A      lpc      0      0
6    C      lpc      8    1.7
```

If I am just trying to get `Value1`, I can do something like

```
>data <- ddply(df, .(Variable), transform, value1 = value1-value1[Diet=="A"])
```

But how to apply this across the entire dataframe? Like to get `Value2` and potentially all other columns with numerical values? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a group by approach with `dplyr`.  For more than one column, just loop `across` those 'Value' columns and do the subtraction grouped by Variable

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Value"), ~ .x - .x[Diet == "A"]), .by = Variable)
```

-output

```
  Diet Variable Value1 Value2
1    A      hpv      0   0.00
2    A      smc      0   0.00
3    B      smc      4   0.78
4    C      smc      7   0.94
5    A      lpc      0   0.00
6    C      lpc      8   1.70
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with base R, no libraries, in this way, provided Diet-Variable combinations are unique:

```r
df <- data.frame(Diet = c("A","A","B","C","A","C"),
                 Variable = c("hpv", "smc", "smc", "smc","lpc", "lpc"),
                 Value1 = c(5, 3, 7, 10, 1, 9),
                 Value2 = c(0.3, 0.56, 1.34, 1.5, 0.7, 2.4))


df <- merge(df, df[df$Diet=="A", -1], by = "Variable", sort = F) 

df <- transform(df, 
          Value1 =  Value1.x - Value1.y, 
          Value2 =  Value2.x - Value2.y)

subset(df, select = c(Diet, Variable, Value1, Value2))
#>   Diet Variable Value1 Value2
#> 1    A      hpv      0   0.00
#> 2    A      smc      0   0.00
#> 3    B      smc      4   0.78
#> 4    C      smc      7   0.94
#> 5    A      lpc      0   0.00
#> 6    C      lpc      8   1.70
```

First you merge (join) df with df fiiltered by "A"
Then substract the columns from the left and the rigth join (x and y)
Then select the desired columns.

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `by`, subtraction, and `unsplit`.

```
by(df, df$Variable, \(x) {x[c('Value1', 'Value2')] <-
  t(t(x[c('Value1', 'Value2')]) - unlist(x[x$Diet == 'A', c('Value1', 'Value2')]));x}) |> 
  unsplit(df$Variable)
#   Diet Variable Value1 Value2
# 1    A      hpv      0   0.00
# 2    A      smc      0   0.00
# 3    B      smc      4   0.78
# 4    C      smc      7   0.94
# 5    A      lpc      0   0.00
# 6    C      lpc      8   1.70
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Diet = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C"), Variable = c("hpv", 
"smc", "smc", "smc", "lpc", "lpc"), Value1 = c(5, 3, 7, 10, 1, 
9), Value2 = c(0.3, 0.56, 1.34, 1.5, 0.7, 2.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```